# Views in Drupal: ignore arguments

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-views

In Drupal I am working with a view that takes a couple of arguments; the nid argument is just passes along to the next page, but the other three arguments it uses to retrieve content. The problem seems to be that the view uses all arguments to retrieve content, which obviously doesn't work since the presence of nid will always return one single row.

So how do i perform the search (retrieve the content pages) using the three arguments while leaving nid intact as it needs to be passed to another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the first argument is a nid, and you want that argument to have no effect on the outcome of the view (no filtering)?

If so, adjust the **Validator options** for the first (nid) argument.

- Set **Validator** to **PHP Code**.
- Leave **PHP validate code** blank and the argument will always be considered invalid.
- Set **Action to take if argument does not validate** to **Display all values**.

This will have the effect of ignoring the first argument.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to achieve. And thanks to your solution it works - thanks a lot :)

Comment: THe problem i got now is that the arguments aren't used by the corresponding filters i've set up. The filters show up but they don't load the values of the arguments in, say, a drop down or textfield.